# Positioning elements for a tooltip

Tags: html, css, positioning

I am sorry if this is really a newbie question - or if it is very simple...

I am trying to make a very basic image tooltip based only on CSS ( no JS ).

Fiddle here :http://jsfiddle.net/ufs44/1/

My problem is how to distance the image from the link in order for it not to obscure the text.

I really would like to make it with only CSS (later I will add some transitions) But right now, the tooltip is always hiding the other links below.

Doing `position:relative` actually makes the whole page "jump" because it is changing from `display:none` to `display:block` and the space is missing for the element...

I would like to know how I can make the tooltip to appear ABOVE the link for example, or to the side...

Comment: Setting `left:<value>` or `top`, or `right` or `bottom` ? - http://jsfiddle.net/5W5bB/1/

Comment: @RobSedgwick SO I got 2 answers , both work. Onestating I should use position:relative; the other position:absolute; which one would be more correct to support all browsers ?

Comment: The element that contains the `position:absolute` element would be set to `position:relative` if you want the 'absolute' element to be 'relatively' positioned to it. eg setting `left:100px` is 100px relative to the left of the containing element.

Comment: To stop the 'jump' you mentioned - use `position:absolute` on the image with parent (`.thelink`) `position:relative`

Comment: Both answers in fact say this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `position: relative;` within the link itself, and then position the image tooltip absolutely.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h5HuL/1/)

Comment: this is still making problem with long links.. Can I position it ABOVE the link ? http://jsfiddle.net/qLeg3/2/

Comment: Yeah, thats the reason for adding relative to the link itself; absolute positioning will base itself on the closest parent element with something other than static positioning...updated my fiddle to illustrate using negative values to position it above the containing element

Answer (score 1):

> how to distance the image from the link in order for it not to obscure
>   the text .

Elements with css `position:absolute` are positioned using css `left` , `right`, `bottom`, `top`

As the comment -  http://jsfiddle.net/5W5bB/1 - using `left`

```
left:200px;
```